# prove that normality satisfies intermediate subgroup condition

Tags: group-theory

How to prove that normality satisfies intermediate subgroup condition?

That is, to prove this: Let $H\leq K\leq G$ be groups s.t. $H \triangleleft G$ ($H$ is normal in $G$), then $H \triangleleft K$.

Comment: This follows immediately from just about every definition of normal subgroup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$H$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $g^{-1}Hg=H$ for all $g$ in $G$. But any $k$ in $K$ is also in $G$.